# Spring Boot disables GET request for static pages when POST is specified

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create an account controller using Spring Boot. I have an html file for the login page located under static/login.html. The page loads perfectly fine when I do not map a POST request to the same path.

I have an AccountController class:

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Account login(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {
        // code
    }
}
```

This controller disables the GET request to the html page. When trying to access the page, I receive;

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

So my question is essentially, how do I get both the POST and GET request working at the same time. If there is a better file structure I can use for the static content, please suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public Account login(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {
    // code
}
```

This way, the controller mapping will be available for both methods

**UPDATE**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String serveLogin(... (if needed) ) {
    // code to serve your static content
    return "index.html"; 
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Account login(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {

    // code to handle your login form POST submit
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion does not map the GET method to the static content. Your code maps both GET and POST to the same method. What I need is for GET to respond with the static webpage and POST to map to the method.

Comment: My bad, totally misunderstood your question. You can have 2 different mappings for the same path (/login), one for the GET method serving your static content, and one for the POST method, handling your form submit. Please see update

Comment: Thank you for the update. What I don't understand is if Spring has some way to maintain its automatic static content serving (which required no configuration on my part). As such, can you elaborate on the `// code to server your static content` ?